# Does `getpid()` return different values in each thread of a process?

Tags: c, pthreads

In Pthreads man page, it was mentioned that

> Calls to getpid(2) return a different value in each thread

in LinuxThreads section.

I have  created two threads and just printed the PID in them. But in both, the PIDs are same.

```
int main () 
{
    //pid_t pid;
    pthread_t tid[2];
    {
        printf("In main, PID : %d, PPID : %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        pthread_create(&(tid[0]), NULL, &(f),NULL);
        pthread_create(&(tid[1]), NULL, &(g),NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

void *g()
{
    printf("My PID in G : %d, PPID : %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
}

void* f()
{
    printf("My PID in F : %d, PPID : %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
}
```

Below is the output I got,

**In main, PID : 5219, PPID : 5214

My PID in F : 5219, PPID : 5214

My PID in G : 5219, PPID : 5214**

I need to know whether I have misunderstood anything wrongly here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mention with the explanation saying,

> The LinuxThreads implementation deviates from the POSIX.1
>   specification in a number of ways, including the following:
>
> Calls to getpid(2) return a different value in each thread.

But you are highly likely using `POSIX Threads`, not `The LinuxThreads`. In POSIX, threads belong to a process and each has same `PID`.